# Is there a way to run a list of different action methods on an object in Nunit using TestCase?

Tags: c#, nunit

Say I have the following:

```
  [Test]
  // would like to parameterize the parameters in call AND the call itself
  public void Test()
  {
      var res1 = _sut.Method1(1);
      var res2 = _sut.Method2("test");
      var res3 = _sit.Method3(3);

      Assert.That(res1, Is.Null);
      Assert.That(res2, Is.Null);
      Assert.That(res3, Is.Null);
  }
```

I'd like to parameterize the tests using the TestCase/TestCaseSource attribute including the call itself.  Due to the repetitive nature of the tests, each method needs to be called with slightly different parameters, but I need to be able to tag a different call for each of the different parameters.  Is this even possible in Nunit? If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: Hi. I know this is easily possible using MbUnit... With NUnit, I think you could do it using a DB and storing the value in this DB, then parametrize your test with a datasource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [TestCaseSource](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6), you should be able to loop over an array of values and invoke the desired methods, for example like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
  private Sut _sut;

  public TestClass()
  {
    _sut = new Sut(...);
  }

  private IEnumerable<object> TestCases
  {
    get
    {
      var values = new object[,] { { 1, "test", 3 }, { 2, "hello", 0 }, ... };

      for (var i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); ++i)
      {
          yield return _sut.Method1((int)values[i,0]);
          yield return _sut.Method2((string)values[i,1]);
          yield return _sut.Method3((int)values[i,2]);
      }
    }
  }

  [TestCaseSource("TestCases")]
  public void Test(object val)
  {
    Assert.That(val, Is.Null);
  }
}
```

Note that the `_sut` instance needs to be instantiated in the `TestClass` constructor. It is not sufficient to initialize it within a `[SetUp]` or `[TestFixtureSetUp]` method.

In case you need different `_sut` instantiations for different method invocations, you could create a collection of `Sut` instances in the constructor, and access the relevant `Sut` item within the `for` loop of the `TestCases` getter. Alternatively, you could even loop over all `Sut` items in the getter...

Comment: Interesting suggestion, however I'm getting 'cannot convert expression type 'lambda expression' to yield type Tuple<Func<object, object>, object>...

Comment: I have updated the example, but I'll look into the code more deeply. Will get back as soon as possible.

Comment: I overdid it the first time :-) How about the updated example?

Comment: Everything compiles ok now, what was the change? New problem is, the _sut is null in the TestCases property. I 'new' the _sut in the Init() of the fixture. Maybe this is too late?...

Comment: I do not know the exact order of execution here, but I tried initializing `_sut` in the `TestClass` constructor instead, and then `_sut` is sufficiently initialized within the `TestCases` property. I'll update the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, there is no such built-in mechanism in NUnit. However, if multiple methods exist in a test, I think it would be a better practice to split them into separate tests.

That being said, provided that you always call these methods on the same object (`_sut`), you can do this with reflection (also if you decide to take the incurred overhead).

For example, add a string parameter in your TestCaseSource, and in the test method invoke it like this:

```
Type type = _sut.GetType();
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);
object result = methodInfo.Invoke(_sut, null);
```

Things will quickly get complicated when each method you want to parameterize will take a different number of arguments though. Debugging and seeing which test failed will also be much harder. It's best if you could split these tests.

Comment: Yeah I kind of think while nice, it is overkill. I've reduced the no. lines in each Test by create helper methods so its not too bad repeating the tests. However, I do think this kind of thing would be useful in testing state machines etc...